# My if statement executes both if's rather than just 1

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement

So I'm learning Bash and I have no idea why my `if` statement isn't working (working in putty if it makes any difference). I've tried looking online for how an `if` statement is supposed to be built and followed it making sure I got all the details correct. When I run it both of the `if`'s come out positive and both of them get executed rather than just 1.

```
echo -n "Enter file name: "
read x

echo "file $x with numbers (Y/N)?"
read y

if [ "$y"="n" ];
then
        cat $x
fi

if [ "$y"="y" ];
then
        cat -n $x
fi

exit
```

can anyone help please?

Comment: Use `if [ "$y" = "n" ]`. Note the [extra whitespace](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html#SCOMPARISON1).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I saw sometimes people put a space between the = sign and sometimes don't. What's the difference?

Comment: @Uranus I answered it below. its an assignment if you don't use whitespace.

Comment: okay thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @MayurNagekar : It's not an assignment, see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40546826/3744681)

Comment: So now if i wanted to make an if with 3 variables like if [ $x + $y = $z ]; then echo "$x+$y=$z" it gives me an error even though there's spaces. how do the signs work for this kind of condition?

Answer (score 0):

Remember there needs to be a whitespace in your if condition else it becomes an assignment. https://uvesway.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/some-whitespace-pitfalls-in-bash-programming/

Answer (score 0):

`"$y"="n"` is **neither a conditional test nor an assignment**. It's just a single string e.g, if `$y` is 'y', then `"$y"="n"` is the same as the literal `'y=n'` and this literal string is being treated as a single parameter to the `test` (`[`) command.

A condition like below is always evaluated to true:

```
if [ abcd ]; then echo true; fi
```

while an empty string makes it false:

```
if [ '' ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

> White spaces aren't optional (everywhere) in bash. Even though the `[ abcd` thingy looks like a syntax, it's not; `[` is a command (`test`) and `abcd` is its first positional parameter.